# How to migrate mail accounts from one server to another without losing them?

Tags: email, web, hosting

I am moving my bussines website from a shared Bluehost server to a MyHosting VPS. The only problem here is that we have some mail accounts that we use to receive orders from our customers, so we can't change the email direction or else we would lose some customers. Is there any way to change the account's server without losing the accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You can take backup of your email on your local system by using Outlook or Thunderbird etc.

Then you can create same domain & mail accounts on your VPS.